# how to implement using for loop?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use spinner button in android application. Now the situation is that i want an array list of 18 to 99.Can anybody Implement the following code using for loop.

```
private void spElements() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> ages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ages.add("18");
    ages.add("19");
    ages.add("20");
    ages.add("21");
    ages.add("22");
    ages.add("23");
    ages.add("24");
    ages.add("25");
    ages.add("26");
    ages.add("27");
    ages.add("28");
    ages.add("29");..................ages.add("99");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ages);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I seriously recommend you follow some Java tutorials. If you were unable to work out the answer yourself then you're going to have a tough time with other more complex problems.

Comment: `Can anybody Implement the following code using for loop.` - yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 18; i <= 99; i++) {
   ages.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```